# C++ Compilation Error -Unknown Type Name

Tags: c++, data-structures, compiler-errors

For my CS assignment, we were to implement a binary heap to replace the STL priority queue on her working program, that was the first part. For the second part, we have to re-implement it using polymorphism.  I finished the first part, and all I did was divide all classes into its own header and source file, and I get a massive amount of error. On xcode it says unknown type name 'Event'.

I tried changing the #ifndef stuff ( sorry I don't know what it's called ), but no luck.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

David

---

I'm using xcode, but here's the error message from Terminal:

```
In file included from ModemSimV2.h:5,
                 from Event.h:4,
                 from Event.cpp:1:
EventHeap.h:18: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
EventHeap.h:18: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘Event’ with no type
EventHeap.h:19: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘Event’ with no type
EventHeap.h:19: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘*’ token
EventHeap.h:23: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘Event’ with no type
EventHeap.h:23: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘*’ token
In file included from Event.h:4,
                 from EventHeap.h:8,
                 from EventHeap.cpp:1:
ModemSimV2.h:11: error: ‘EventHeap’ has not been declared
ModemSimV2.h:23: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘EventHeap’ with no type
ModemSimV2.h:23: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘*’ token
EventHeap.cpp: In constructor ‘EventHeap::EventHeap()’:
EventHeap.cpp:6: error: call of overloaded ‘Event()’ is ambiguous
Event.h:10: note: candidates are: Event::Event(int, int)
Event.h:9: note:                 Event::Event()
EventHeap.cpp: In constructor ‘EventHeap::EventHeap(int)’:
EventHeap.cpp:12: error: call of overloaded ‘Event()’ is ambiguous
Event.h:10: note: candidates are: Event::Event(int, int)
Event.h:9: note:                 Event::Event()
EventHeap.cpp: In member function ‘void EventHeap::buildHeap(int)’:
EventHeap.cpp:40: error: call of overloaded ‘Event()’ is ambiguous
Event.h:10: note: candidates are: Event::Event(int, int)
Event.h:9: note:                 Event::Event()
```

---

main.cpp:

```
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>  // for greater()
#include <climits>     // for INT_MAX
#include <iostream>
#include "random.h"
#include "ModemSimV2.h"
#include "Event.h"
#include "EventHeap.h"


using namespace std;

// Simple main to test ModemSim class.
int main( )
{
    int numModems;
    int totalTime;
    double avgConnectTime;
    int dialInFrequency;

    cout << "Enter number of modems, length of simulation,\n"
    << " average connect time, how often calls occur: ";

    cin >> numModems >> totalTime >>
    avgConnectTime >> dialInFrequency;

    EventHeap eHeap( numModems );
    ModemSimV2 s( numModems, avgConnectTime, dialInFrequency, eHeap );
    s.runSim( totalTime );

    return 0;
}
```

Event.h:

```
#ifndef EVENT_P2_H
#define EVENT_P2_H

#include "ModemSimV2.h"

class Event{
    //enum { DIAL_IN = 1, HANGUP = 2 };
public:
    Event( );
    Event( int name = 0, int tm = 0 );

    bool operator > ( const Event & rhs ) const;
    bool operator < ( const Event & rhs ) const;
    bool operator <= ( const Event & rhs ) const;
    bool operator != ( const Event & rhs ) const;

    //void process( ModemSimV2 m );

    friend class ModemSimV2;

private:
    int who;        // the number of the user
    int time;       // when the event will occur
    int what;       // DIAL_IN or HANGUP
};

/*
class Dialin : public Event{

public:
    Dialin( );
    void process( ModemSimV2 m );
};*/
#endif
```

---

Event.cpp:

```
#include "Event.h"

Event::Event( ) {

}

Event::Event( int name, int tm )
: time( tm ), who( name ) { 
    return;
}

bool Event::operator > ( const Event & rhs ) const { 
    return time > rhs.time; 
}

bool Event::operator < ( const Event & rhs ) const { 
    return time < rhs.time; 
}

bool Event::operator <= ( const Event & rhs ) const { 
    return time < rhs.time; 
}

bool Event::operator != ( const Event & rhs ) const { 
    return time != rhs.time; 
}
```

---

EventHeap.h:

```
#ifndef BINARY_HEAP_P2_H
#define BINARY_HEAP_P2_H

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

#include "Event.h"

class EventHeap{
public:
    EventHeap( );
    EventHeap( int numIndex );

    bool empty( ) const;
    const int & findMin( ) const;

    void push( const Event & x );
    Event * pop();

private:
    int size;         // Number of elements in heap
    Event *array;            // The heap array

    void buildHeap( int index );
    void reIndex( int hole );
    int getLeft( int index ) const;
    int getRight( int index )const;
    int getParent( int index )const;
};


#endif
```

---

EventHeap.cpp:

```
#include "EventHeap.h"

//Constructor
EventHeap::EventHeap( ) {

    array = new Event[1];
    size = 0;
}

EventHeap::EventHeap( int numVals ) { 

    array = new Event[numVals];
    size = 0;
}

//insert
void EventHeap::push( const Event &e ) {

    array[size] = e;
    reIndex( size );
    size++;
}

//removes the min val   
Event* EventHeap::pop( ) {

    Event *e = &array[0];
    array[0] = array[size - 1];
    size--;
    if( !empty( ) )
        buildHeap(0);

    return e;
}

//re do
void EventHeap::buildHeap( int nodeIndex ) {

    int leftChildIndex, rightChildIndex, minIndex;
    Event tmp;

    leftChildIndex = getLeft(nodeIndex);

    rightChildIndex = getRight(nodeIndex);

    if (rightChildIndex >= size) {

        if (leftChildIndex >= size)

            return;

        else

            minIndex = leftChildIndex;

    } else {

        if (array[leftChildIndex] <= array[rightChildIndex])

            minIndex = leftChildIndex;

        else

            minIndex = rightChildIndex;

    }

    if (array[nodeIndex] > array[minIndex]) {

        tmp = array[minIndex];

        array[minIndex] = array[nodeIndex];

        array[nodeIndex] = tmp;

        buildHeap(minIndex);

    }
}


//re index
void EventHeap::reIndex( int hole ) {

    while( array[hole] != NULL && array[hole] <  array[getParent( hole )] ) {
        int pIndex = getParent( hole );
        Event temp( array[hole] );
        array[hole] = array[pIndex];
        array[pIndex] = temp;
        hole = pIndex;
    }
}

//is Empty
bool EventHeap::empty() const {
    return ( size == 0 );
}

int EventHeap::getLeft( int index ) const {
    return ( index * 2 ) + 1;
}

int EventHeap::getRight( int index ) const {
    return ( index * 2 ) + 2;
}

int EventHeap::getParent( int index ) const {
    return ( index - 1 ) / 2;
}
```

---

ModemSimV2.h

```
#ifndef MODEM_SIM_V2_H
#define MODEM_SIM_V2_H

#include "Event.h"
#include "EventHeap.h"
#include "random.h"


class ModemSimV2{
public:
    ModemSimV2( int modems, double avgLen, int callIntrvl, EventHeap e );
    // Add a call to eventSet at the current time,
    // and schedule one for delta in the future.
    void nextCall( int delta );

    // Run the simulation
    void runSim( int stoppingTime );// = INT_MAX );

    // friend class Event;

private:
    Random r;                       // A random source
    EventHeap *eventSet;                    // Pending events

    // Basic parameters of the simulation
    int freeModems;                 // Number of modems unused
    const double avgCallLen;        // Length of a call
    const int freqOfCalls;          // Interval between calls
};

#endif
```

---

ModemSimV2.cpp

```
#include "ModemSimV2.h"

// Constructor for ModemSim.
ModemSimV2::ModemSimV2( int modems, double avgLen, int callIntrvl, EventHeap e )
: freeModems( modems ), avgCallLen( avgLen ),
freqOfCalls( callIntrvl ), r( (int) time( 0 ) )
{
    eventSet = &e;
    nextCall( freqOfCalls );  // Schedule first call
}

// Place a new DIAL_IN event into the event queue.
// Then advance the time when next DIAL_IN event will occur.
// In practice, we would use a random number to set the time.
void ModemSimV2::nextCall( int delta ){
    static int nextCallTime = 0;
    static int userNum = 0;

    eventSet->push( Event( userNum++, nextCallTime ) );
    nextCallTime += delta;
}

// Run the simulation until stopping time occurs.
void ModemSimV2::runSim( int stoppingTime ){
    Event *e;

    while( !eventSet->empty( ) ){
        e = eventSet->pop();
        if ( e->time > stoppingTime )
            break;
        //e->process( this );
        nextCall( freqOfCalls );
    }
}
```

Comment: firstly, dont have two constructors that do the same thing. you cant have Event() and Event (var = 0). they both do the same thing and if you have no value, theres no way way of deciding which one to pick

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Event.h` includes `ModemSimV2.h`. `ModemSimV2.h` includes `Event.h`. That's not going to work without a little help.

You should read up on [forward declarations](http://www-subatech.in2p3.fr/~photons/subatech/soft/carnac/CPP-INC-1.shtml). See [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-to-use-forward-declaration) for more information.

Comment: Well, that solved the problem, but I did that only because Event needs to know about ModemSim, ModemSim needs to know about EventHeap, EventHeap needs to know about Event... it's a vicious circle. How would I go about solving that?

Comment: @David `Event` doesn't need the *definition* of `ModemSimV2`. It only uses it as a `friend class`, so a forward declaration will suffice. Read the links from my answer.

Comment: Right, but still one class would have to be declared before the other one even if you put it all on the same file using forward declaration. And whatever on the top still doesn't know what's below it.  I guess that's something to improve on in my implementation?

Comment: never-mind, I think I got it. Didn't realize there was a second link. Thank you.